# Proof of optimal linear LMS estimator

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, least-squares, parameter-estimation

Given two real zero mean random variables $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, the linear LMS of $\mathbf{x}$ given $\mathbf{y}$ such that $$\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{K_o}\mathbf{y}$$

is given by

$$\mathbf{K_o}=\mathbf{R_{xy}}\mathbf{R_y^{-1}}$$

I'm trying to prove this but I get stuck in the final step. We want to find the matrix $\mathbf{K_o}$ such that the mean-square error is minimized.

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}})(\mathbf{x}-\hat{\mathbf{x}})^T]
&=
\mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{K_o}\mathbf{y})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{K_o}\mathbf{y})^T]
\\&=
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{K_o}\mathbf{y}\mathbf{x}^T]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{K_o}\mathbf{y})^T]+\mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{K_oy})(\mathbf{K_oy})^T]
\\&=
\mathbf{R_{x}}-\mathbf{K_o}\mathbf{R_{yx}} - \mathbf{R_{xy}}\mathbf{K_o}^T + \mathbf{K_o}\mathbf{R_{y}}\mathbf{K_o}^T
\end{align}
$$

If these values were all scalars, then it is easy to see that the minimum would be achieved (i.e. the derivative would equal zero) in $k_o = r_{xy}/r_y$, as stated at the beginning.

But how can one continue the sketch of proof above when all variables are matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to minimize is $\mathbb{E}\left[\text{Tr}\left((\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\hat x)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\hat x})}^T\right) \right]$, otherwise what does minimize mean for a matrix?

If you agree, you can do the following
$$
f(\boldsymbol{K_0}) = \text{Tr}\left(\boldsymbol{R_{x}}-\boldsymbol{K_0}\boldsymbol{R_{yx}}-\boldsymbol{R_{xy}}\boldsymbol{K_0}^T+\boldsymbol{K_0}\boldsymbol{R_{y}}
\boldsymbol{K_0}^T\right)
$$
Find the derivative with respect to $\boldsymbol{K_0}$ and set it to zero, yielding
$$
\boldsymbol{0}-\boldsymbol{R_{yx}}^T-\boldsymbol{R_{xy}}+2\boldsymbol{K_0}\boldsymbol{R_y}=0
$$
yielding, since $\boldsymbol{R_{yx}^T}=\boldsymbol{R_{xy}}$
$$
\boldsymbol{K_0} = \boldsymbol{R_{xy}}\boldsymbol{R_y}^{-1} 
$$which is the minimum since the second derivative is $\boldsymbol{R_y}\geq0$.

Comment: "Find the derivative with respect to $\mathbf{K_o}$", can one do that? Calculate the derivative of a function with respect to a _matrix_?

Comment: Forgot to add Trace :-) It is getting late.

Comment: Minimizing $\mathbb{E}\left[(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\hat x)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\hat x})}^T \right]$ makes sense to me, as $(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\hat x)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\hat x})}^T$ is a scalar (precisely, it's the norm of $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\hat x}$ squared). So why would I add the trace?

Comment: It is a scalar if you define $\boldsymbol{x}$ as a row vector. But I am a bit confused now. You show that the expectation is a matrix in your question.